# Is a Microsoft.SharePoint.dll reference on a local machine enough to connect me to a server folder?

Tags: sharepoint

I'm getting this when I try to connect to a SharePoint 2013 site folder from a simple .NET console app I cobbled together:

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load
>   file or assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Library, Version=15.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=...

Would I actually have to have some form of SharePoint 2013 installed onto the Windows runtime on which I'm attempting to run even this one SPContext statement?

```
    public static void Whatever(){
                    SPSite oSiteCollection = SPContext.Current.Site;
    }
```

Microsoft.SharePoint.dll for 2013 is compiled into my build as a reference.  It all builds fine; no errors.

What is the minimum set of libraries necessary to run that on a Windows machine?  (I'm trying to connect to a SharePoint site I see on my browser.)

Thanks for any info/help.

Comment: no it is not.  you need to be on the server to use that DLL.  but you can use the Client SDK or CSOM to access SharePoint from a remote server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Microsoft.SharePoint.dll is server side object model, if you use this library, the app need to run in SharePoint server which SharePoint is installed.

You could use client side object model(the dlls like Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.xxx) in remote server(where SharePoint don't install).

[Check here for sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-client-library-code)